# Share vmware network with other host and other computers

Tags: macos, network, vmware

I have a USB NIC (Bear Extender) that does not work under Yosemite or El Cap.  I have a VM running Mavericks that can use the NIC.  How can I share the internet out of the VM so that my macbook pro can use it?

The USB NIC works in the VMWare Fusion Pro 8.0.1 guest running 10.8.  I just need to know if there is a way to share that network link with the host so it can access the internet.

Comment: So VMWare product X Y Z version is up to guessing? Also - to be clear, you want the VM to be configured to get the USB port directly (are you aware how to do that) and then you want the client OS to be Mavericks and then to enable internet sharing (are you aware how to do that) and then have the host OS somehow use a second network connection to the NIC from it's main network connection to then access the rest of the network that it already has access to? I don't mean to be negative, just I'm looking for some details so this doesn't get closed as "too broad"

Comment: @bmike I have updated the question.  The basic question is how can I share my internet out of the guest into the host using VMWare Fusion 8.0.1 Pro.